# how to extract data from a log file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, split

I'm new to python script so pls kindly help me

my log file is this

```
xxx="asdff" yyy="qwernlk" zzz"jsfhla"
xxx="asdff" yyy="qwernlk" zzz"jsfhla"
xxx="asdff" yyy="qwernlk" zzz"jsfhla"
xxx="asdff" yyy="qwernlk" zzz"jsfhla"
```

I need the output as

```
    xxx        yyyy         zzz
asdff      qwernlk        jsfhla
asdff      qwernlk        jsfhla
asdff      qwernlk        jsfhla
asdff      qwernlk        jsfhla
```

and this output must be in csv file format....
(this csv file must have common header and the extracted value must come automatically acoording to the header......)

thank you in advance!!!!!

pls help me guys......

Comment: Well, you read the file, you parse it line by line and write the data to another file. Where did you stuck?

Comment: I can split the file but i cant place according to the header....

Comment: Consider using the module [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: yea i used csv module but the header is not coming automatically

Comment: You either write it manually, or use `DictWriter.writeheader`.

Comment: Even i write it like u said, the script is not matching according to the header....

Comment: Provide your code and output.

Comment: this is the code `fread = open(fileread, "r")
resultFile = open("out.csv",'w')
wr = csv.writer(resultFile)


header = [
['xxx','yyy','zzz']

]
wr.writerows(header)


try:
    

    for line in fread:
            regex = re.findall(r'"(.+?)"',line)
            wr.writerow(row)`

Comment: Please post all your code in you original question. Besides, where is `row` defined?

Comment: Do you see how this problem is different from "header is not coming automatically?" Review your parsing logic, so that it handles all the cases.

Comment: ok then pls send the codes\

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: u pls rewrite the code that i placed in the comment and pls post the answer below.....

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a code-writing or spoon-feeding service. You know where the problem is and the solution is nearly trivial.

Comment: ok tq so much for ur comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have took that input of yours and assembled it using a dict. You write that in a csv.

```
file_name = open('log.txt','rb')
name_list = []
name_dict = {}
for line in file_name:
    line = line.split()
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i].split('=')[0] in name_dict:
            name_dict[line[i].split('=')[0]].append(line[i].split('=')[1])
        else:
            name_dict[line[i].split('=')[0]] = []
            name_dict[line[i].split('=')[0]].append(line[i].split('=')[1])
for key in name_dict.keys():
    print key, name_dict[key]

Output:
xxx ['"asdff"', '"asdff"', '"asdff"', '"asdff"']
yyy ['"qwernlk"', '"qwernlk"', '"qwernlk"', '"qwernlk"']
zzz ['"jsfhla"', '"jsfhla"', '"jsfhla"', '"jsfhla"']
```

Here your variables are the keys(xxxx,yyyy,zzzz) with the respective values which you have assigned for it.

Comment: i have little problem in it "**IndexError: list index out of range**" pls tell me if want to increase the count or i should use it in for loop

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: im getting an error msg "**IndexError: list index out of range**"

Comment: See to your input, there are '=' for xxxx, yyyy but not for zzzz. So I interpreted 'zzzz' as 'zzzz='. Is my interpretation right? or there won't be '=' for zzzz

Comment: sry i didnt noticed it,"=" will come in "zzzz" also

Comment: Then add '=' and run this. You'll get the output which I have given.

Comment: yea i added but the output is coming xxx
yyy
zzz
xxx
yyy
zzz
xxx
yyy
zzz
xxx
yyy
zzz
xxx ['"asdff"', '"asdff"', '"asdff"', '"asdff"']
yyy ['"qwernlk"', '"qwernlk"', '"qwernlk"', '"qwernlk"']
zzz ['"jsfhla"', '"jsfhla"', '"jsfhla"', '"jsfhla"']

Comment: thank you so much the output is coming correctly and another doubt if the log file doesn't have **yyyy** in certain line then wat to do